# Swift 2 Error: Argument labels '(value:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: swift, swift2, nsnumber

I am trying to randomize circles falling for my rhythm game, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is the closest I have gotten:

```
var alternator = 0
var fallTimer:NSTimer?
var flag:Bool = true

let circleIndexes = (0..<5).map { return NSNumber(value: $0) }

let randomIndexes = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(circleIndexes) as! [Int]

func fallCircleWrapper() {

    if (flag == true) {
        self.alternator += 1
    } else {
        self.alternator -= 1
    }

    if (self.alternator == 0) {
        flag = true
    } else if (self.alternator == 5) {
        flag = false
    }

    self.hitAreaArray[randomIndexes[self.alternator]].emitNote(self.texture!)
}
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
let circleIndexes = (0..<5).map { return NSNumber(value: $0) }
```

I am new to this so forgive me if there is an easy solution I am not seeing, and please feel free to suggest a better way of going about this if you have one. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using Swift 2? The latest stable version of Xcode doesn't even support Swift 2.x – you really should update to Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

That's Swift 3 code. The initializer for Swift 2 NSNumber is:

```
NSNumber(integer: ...)
```

So, your line would become:

```
let circleIndexes = (0..<5).map { return NSNumber(integer: $0) }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. However, I have a new problem. This line: `let randomIndexes = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(circleIndexes) as! [Int]`
gives the error "Instance member 'circleIndexes' cannot be used on type 'GameScene'. What should I do?

Comment: @shadokyr, please avoid asking multiple questions in the comments. If you have another issue, open another question, so that others with the same problems as you in the future will be able to find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is Swift 3 code.

```
NSNumber(value:)
```

Swift 2 version:

```
NSNumber(integer:)
```

You just need to change to this

```
let circleIndexes = (0..<5).map { return NSNumber(integer: $0) }
```